# Posting Data To Sub-Domain URL on Localhost

Tags: android, localhost

Hello I am building my first android app, I am currently trying to post data to a URL on my local server.  When I try with my live server it works however with my local server it does not, nothing happens at all, I get no response.

This is the route in my app on my localhost: http://admin.website.dev

I changed my hosts file and virtual host configuration on my localhost so that any address with the extension ".dev" points to a folder on my localhost. eg. "localhost/website"

Is there a reason this does not work in my android app when I try posting data?
I have already added the INTERNET permission in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Since android 5, you need to make a POST on DNS valid URL.
I'm not sure if your changes on hosts file will work.

Comment: Thank you for your time but this should be a comment and not an answer.